# JS/Jquery - using variable in json selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to use a variable when selecting data from a json source like this.
The json is retrieved with jquery `getJSON()`.

```
"prices":[{
    "fanta":10,
    "sprite":20,
}]

var beverage = fanta;
var beverage_price = data.prices.beverage;
```

Now `beverage_price = 10`

```
var beverage = sprite;
var beverage_price = data.prices.beverage;
```

Now `beverage_price = 20`

When I try to do it like in the examples, the script tries to look up the beverage entry in prices.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Use square bracket notation `data.prices[beverage]`.

Comment: ... `data.prices` is an array: `[0]` is required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variables in dot notation like square bracket notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102704/how-to-use-variables-in-dot-notation-like-square-bracket-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) mentioned in the comment, `data.prices` is an array, you need to access its first element with `[0]` which contains prices `{ "fanta":10, "sprite":20}`

here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/2E8AH/

Or else you can make `data.prices` an object like below : (if it is in your control)

```
var data = {
    "prices" : 
        {
            "fanta":10,
            "sprite":20,
        }
};
```

and can access without `[0]` like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Y8KtT/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can access it like:

```
var beverage = 'fanta';
var beverage_price = data.prices[0][beverage];
```